# Codeigniter RESTful API

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

I have a mysql database with a table which contains several brands of cars. I need to create an API for all, so right now I have something like this :

```
<?php

require(APPPATH.'libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class carcollection extends REST_Controller{

// AUDI
public function audi_get()  
{ 
    $this->load->database();
    $sql = "SELECT car_id, car_brand, car_model FROM `cars` WHERE car_brand LIKE 'Audi' LIMIT 10";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $data = $query->result();

}

// BMW
public function bmw_get()  
{ 
    $this->load->database();
    $sql = "SELECT car_id, car_brand, car_model FROM `cars` WHERE car_brand LIKE 'BMW' LIMIT 10";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $data = $query->result();

}

...etc..etc.
```

This works fine so far, when I for example enter `http://localhost/myprojects/cars/index.php/api/carcollection/audi` my console/browser gives me the correct data in JSON format. When I enter `http://localhost/myprojects/cars/index.php/api/carcollection/` - I get the error `{"status":false,"error":"Unknown method."}` - but I would like to know how I could do this so that I get all data for once? with the URL shown before without basically changing the SQL queries...

Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include an index route:

```
public function index_get() {
    $this->load->database();
    $sql = "SELECT car_id, car_brand, car_model FROM `cars` LIMIT 10";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $data = $query->result();
}
```